# Angular library with strict = false and app with strict = true in monorepo

Tags: angular

I am building a new app to replace an existing app. I would like to be able to include the old code in the new repository some how so I can route to old components until those components have been rewritten in the new pattern. The biggest issue I have is there is a huge amount of work in making the old components strict compliant. What I am thinking is the best approach would be put all the old code in a library and route to them from the new app.

Is there a way where I can have a mono repo that is a mix of strict and non strict? The --strict=false option only seems to be available for "ng new" and not for "ng add library". I would much prefer to have all the code in a singe project rather that that a separate library project.

Comment: I want to do the same thing but have not found a solution yet. I use a nx monorepo which I want to add a legacy library to an existing app which is in strict mode. I don't want to switch the old library to strict mode yet. Have you found a solution meanwhile?

Comment: I put the old code in a a separate repo, I never did figure out how to get a library in a mono repo to have separate TS config.